# How to append a item from a list to another list?

Tags: python, list, append

I need to print the name of all the itemsthat match the highest price(10.0) as the highestPriceList
My problem is that even if the price match the highest price it does not append. The list is [itemName,price]

```
inventoryList = [['Steak', ' 10'], ['Milk', ' 2'], ['Fruits', ' 10'], ['Canned Corn', ' 0.50']]
highestPriceItem = 10.0
highestPriceList = []

for item in inventoryList:
    if item[1] == highestPriceItem:
        highestPriceList.append(item[0])
print ("Item with highest wholsesale price: ",highestPriceList)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings, where `' 10'` is not the same thing as `10.0`. Use numbers instead:

```
inventoryList = [['Steak', 10], ['Milk', 2], ['Fruits', 10], ['Canned Corn', 0.50]]
highestPriceItem = 10.0
highestPriceList = []

for item in inventoryList:
    if item[1] == highestPriceItem:
        highestPriceList.append(item[0])
print ("Item with highest wholsesale price: ",highestPriceList)
```

---

Or if for a reason not shown in the question, you need to keep strings, then at least compare as numbers:

```
inventoryList = [['Steak', ' 10'], ['Milk', ' 2'], ['Fruits', ' 10'], ['Canned Corn', ' 0.50']]
highestPriceItem = 10.0
highestPriceList = []

for item in inventoryList:
    if float(item[1]) == highestPriceItem:
        highestPriceList.append(item[0])
print ("Item with highest wholsesale price: ",highestPriceList)
```

Comment: The second suggestion works better for me, but how can I print the higestPriceList as normal words, instead of list format(['Steak', 'Fruits'])?

Comment: add a `*` to unpack the list into arguments, like this: `print ("Item with highest wholsesale price: ", *highestPriceList)`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [66]: inventoryList = [['Steak', ' 10'], ['Milk', ' 2'], ['Fruits', ' 10'], ['Canned Corn', ' 0.50']]

In [67]: maxPrice = max(float(L[1]) for L in inventoryList)

In [68]: highestPriceList = [L for L in inventoryList if float(L[1]) == maxPrice]

In [69]: highestPriceList
Out[69]: [['Steak', ' 10'], ['Fruits', ' 10']]
```

Comment: I already have the highest Price, I dont need line[67] to calculate max of prices. And what does L means?

Comment: using `L` the way I did is like saying `for L in inventoryList`

Answer (score 0):

Your list of prices is a string with the first character a space. The comparison is to the floating point number 10.0 As a result, every if in the loop is a false. It should be

```
inventoryList = [['Steak', '10.0'], ['Milk', '2.0'], ['Fruits', '10.0'], ['Canned Corn', '0.50']]
highestPriceItem = 10.0
highestPriceList = []

for item in inventoryList:
  if float(item[1]) == highestPriceItem:
    highestPriceList.append(item[0]) # Only the item is appended and not the price
print ("Item with highest wholsesale price: ",highestPriceList)
```

Alternatively, change the prices to floats in the list. If you have further manipulations that need to be done, then that might save time later on.

Comment: the list is created by the rest of the code I didnt show, so it makes it complicated to turn into a float, but thank you

Comment: @user3311946 Then use the alternate where you say if float(item[1])==highestPriceItem

Comment: @user3311946 I changed the order so that it shows using the float in the if first and then mentions changing the prices in the list if further processing as a number is required.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be a decent (given your constraints) way of doing this. The structure of you `inventoryList` is kept the same and the `highestPriceItem` can keep its current form as well. I've used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a [for statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) to make it more efficient and, more importantly, more readable.

```
inventoryList = [['Steak', ' 10'], ['Milk', ' 2'], ['Fruits', ' 10'], ['Canned Corn', ' 0.50']]
highestPriceItem = 10.0
highestPriceList = [item[0] for item in inventoryList if float(item[1]) == highestPriceItem]

print ("Item with highest wholsesale price: ", highestPriceList)
```